# Excel reads text database - view in PHP, HTML etc

Tags: php, html, excel, text

We have a file on server X, that logs the use of licences for program that we have (in text file - log.txt is our database).

We created Excel that reads from that file (and added additional fields we need for viewing licences state). Now we want to show this data from Excel in HTML or PHP etc. We tried PHP Excel Reader, but that's not optimal for us, because Excel must be open and we must refresh Excel content and then save it, to make any changes in PHP view.

Any idea?  Please help, thanks.

Greetings

Comment: It's probably more sensible to write some VBScript in your Excel that pushes new rows out to a server file that can be accessed from PHP... otherwise you're not going to find many PHP solutions that can access an open Excel file

Comment: Alternatively, why not simply use PHP to read from your log.txt?

Comment: Any good tutorial for 'use PHP to read from your log.txt'? It needs to be easy to have same formulas, that we have in Excel... Thanks.

Comment: How can I read file from server, not from local folder?  $f = fopen("\\server\log.txt", "r");

Comment: You'd have to make sure that the log file was accessible to the PHP script (eg on a shareable drive); and the functionality of most Excel formulae can be replicated in PHP code logic

Comment: How can that be done:'to make sure that the log file was accessible to the PHP script'

Comment: Making a drive/directory shareable is basic network/system administration (though it varies from OS to OS). Writing code to readthe log and handle formulae will depend on the format of your log and the formulae you use/

Comment: How can I write it into HTML table using PHP if my txt file have first row that represents names of the fields and they are divided by |, all the other rows are then acutal data also divided by |

Comment: You're asking very specific questions... raise these as additional questions providing all appropriate information... but clue: PHP has a function called fgetcsv()

Comment: I've helped myself by using  fgetcsv() function, thanks.